Putting `thanks` in one line
I am trying to put all footnotes produced by \thanks in one line, with \hfill between. I tried to follow the way the original \thanks works. I am having trouble putting the footnote marker in the footnote:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\title{Test}
\author{%
    Author1\thanks{bli@bla.com} \and
    Author2\thanks{blu@bla.com} \and
}

\makeatletter
% Put all \thanks in one line
\let\@@thanks\empty
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[1]{\texorpdfstring{%
    \footnotemark
    \ifx\@@thanks\empty
        \protected@xdef\@@thanks{\protect\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]#1}%
    \else
        \protected@xdef\@@thanks{\@@thanks\hfill\protect\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]#1}%
    \fi%
}{}}
\renewcommand\@thanks{\blfootnote{\@@thanks}}

% Footnote without number
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}

prints no markers at all; removing the two \protections gives ! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition. Why do I even need protection here (nothing's written to an aux file, is it?), and why does none of with/without \protect work?

I'm not entirely happy with this, but it works (sort of).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{B}

\title{Test}
\author{%
    Author1\thanks{~bli@bla.com} \and
    Author2\thanks{~blu@bla.com}
}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\thefootnoteA{\@fnsymbol\c@footnoteA}
    \let\c@footnote=\c@footnoteA
    \let\footnotemark=\footnotemarkA
    \let\footnotetext=\footnotetextA
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\let\footnote=\footnoteB
Some text here\footnote{test} and another\footnote{another}.
\end{document}

